# Pingfederate SSO Authentication using SAML2 for Web application and Mobile Application

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, authentication, mobile, saml-2.0

I have implemented PingFederate SSO Authenticaton using SAML2 for Web application. I have used IDP initiated SSO where I redirected to IDP Url and getting SAML response at ACS URL. It's working Fine.

Now I have other mobile application's(Android & IOS) in which I need to implement SSO authentication. So Need I configure different Entity Id for mobile apps at Pingfederate to get different ACS URL's or I can use same IDP URL and ACS URL used in Web application for Mobile application also ? If yes Then How can I differentiate web application authentication and Mobile application authentication.

Comment: Do you want your users to have to login every use, or could you use OAuth to make their first login "sticky"? Ultimately, you should have a conversation with your account's RSA, to have a longer discussion about your needs than what is really possible here.

Comment: I went with alternate approach , I have implement OAuth authentication mechanism for all application (Web, iOS and Android) . Thanks for help.